# New PC not turning screen on with keyboard, only mouse movement Kubuntu 22.04

Tags: kubuntu, suspend, power-management

I have a new pc I recently purchased and installed Kubuntu 22.04 to rid myself of windows.  everything works fine other than for whatever reason when the screen turns off after a few minutes of no activity only my wireless mouse will turn the screen back on to the lock screen.  If I press any key on my wired keyboard, nothing happens.  is there any settings I can change to allow both the keyboard or mouse movements to turn the screen back on?   I do not believe the pc is going to sleep, only locking and turning the screen off.

I ask this because just a while ago my system went unresponsive, screen off and my mouse would not turn the screen back on!  I assumed the batteries in my mouse went dead.  replacing them and the mouse would not re-connect until the PC was back up.  I had to force power off the PC.

PC specs:  I7-12400kf, AMD rx6950xt

P.S. I went with Kubuntu for the kde over gnome environment.